# How to sort integer column properly in jqGird

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, jqgrid

I have jqGrid in place

```
@(Html.Grid("Basic")

      .SetCaption("Basic Grid")

      .AddColumn(new Column("Id")
                     .SetHidden(true))

      .AddColumn(new Column("Name"))
      .AddColumn(new Column("Age").SetFormatter(Formatters.Integer))

      .SetForceFit(true)
      .SetShrinkToFit(true)    
      .SetAutoWidth(true)
      .SetRowNum(10)
      .SetRowList(new[] { 10, 15, 20 })
      .SetViewRecords(true)
      .SetPager("pager")    
      .SetLoadOnce(true)
      .SetGridView(true)          
      .SetToolbarPosition(ToolbarPosition.Top)
      .OnGridComplete("onComplete()")
      )
```

And to make dataType local I setup an ajax call separately and grid binded successfully but what happening wrong is the integer column "in my case Age' is not sorting properly. What I suppose to do to sort it right?

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/Data/",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    var jsonData= data;
                     $("#Basic").jqGrid('setGridParam',
                        {
                            datatype: 'local',
                            data: jsonData
                        }).trigger("reloadGrid");
                },
                error:function () {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a property called **sorttype**, You could try this,

```
sorttype : 'int' or 'integer'
```

Refer the below wiki link,

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options